# Using :remote => true with hover event

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I want to invoke an Ajax call in Rails. I've seen a good way of doing so with the `:remote` option. I've got this working example:

```
<%= button_to('Get Transfers', {:action => 'get_transfers', :section_id => params[:section_id]}, :method => :get, :remote => true) %>
```

However, I don't want the user to invoke the call by pressing a button or clicking a link, but rather invoke it on a Javascript event (hovering over an element).

Is there a way to use `:remote => true`, but invoke it automatically when hovering over an element? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**

To make the button respond to click and hover over some other div you can try doing the following:

In your view you give the button a unique id and add some class to an element that should be act as a trigger:

```
<%= button_to('Get Transfers', {action: 'get_transfers', section_id: params[:section_id]}, method: :get, remote: true}, {id: 'remote_hover_button'}) %>
<div class="some_trigger">Hover me!</div>
```

In your js you want to bind to that trigger element and trigger the click event on the button:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.some_trigger').hover(function(){
    $('#remote_hover_button').trigger('click');
  });
});
```

**Option 2**

Write the ajax manually by creating a div that you hover and provide it with an url to call:

```
<div class="some_trigger" data-url="<%= url_for(action: 'get_transfers', section_id: params[:section_id]) %>">Hover me!</div>
```

Bind to the div and do an ajax call:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.some_trigger').hover(function(){
    $.ajax($(this).data('url'));
  });
});
```

This will actually just trigger the action and not perform anything with the response.
You can bind to the result with something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.some_trigger').hover(function(){
    $.ajax($(this).data('url'))
      .done(function() { alert("success"); })
      .fail(function() { alert("error"); })
      .always(function() { alert("complete"); });
  });
});
```

For more information on ajax function look at the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: Yeah, nice idea (+1), although you end up with a button you don't really need. It feels like a workaround just so you can keep `:remote => true`. Why not write the Ajax call directly? It's not so difficult with jQuery...

Comment: Yes, your second option is more like what I would do. Although, I would probably use [`$.getScript(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) instead of `$.ajax(...)`, because the Ajax-call will probably return some Javascript you want to be executed. If it doesn't return Javascript, you can also use [`$.get(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/).