# Add a line in database during a hover - ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, hover

I want to achieve something in rails: I have a new colony in bdd, by default an element is a 1 for all users.
I have a table "userarticles" which will contain the id of the article and the id of the user for each article that flew over
So I want that when an over a div with a "new" tab disappears and that it puts in database that the user saw the article

so, my problem is that when my JQuery request to remove the div it works but I can not make rail requests

```js
<script>
$('.newness').hover(
function() {
$(this).addClass('hover);
//i want to put my rails function there
//I try this
//$(this).innerHTML('<%= article.id %>')
//but he return my all time the same ID.. 
}
</script>
```

```html
<!--rest of my code -->
<h5> <%= article.title %> </h5>
<div class="newness">new</div>
<!--rest of my code-->
```

here the result :

[Result](https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2018/21/3/1527069190-capture-d-ecran-2018-05-23-11-52-00.png)

Sorry for my english,
Ben

Comment: You should add an hidden form to the page and trigger the form submission, look [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html). In particular the [chapter 4](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#server-side-concerns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a single js script that must control many articles blocks. So, you can put <%= article.id %> to script each time, but script run once after the page loaded. That means you put to js only last article id.

But you can mark HTML block(use data attribute) and then just read the note. For example:

```
<div class="newness" data-id='<%= article.id %>'>new</div>
```

And then write you js once:

```
<script>
  $('.newness').hover(
    function() {
      $(this).addClass('hover);
      //read your note there
      myArticleId = $(this).data('id');
      // console.log(myArticleId);
      // do something with id or send ajax request
    }
  )
</script>
```

Comment: Actualy Working Thanks, did u know how to add one line in my database, i have one table user_articles with user_id and article_id

Comment: Migration uses to change database tables(create, rename, add or delete fields). Example: "rails g migration AddFieldToUserArticles field_name:string && rake db:migrate". You can handle create a migration, but generator adds the timestamp to the filename that helps manage migration. After generation and before 'rake db:migrate' you can edit migration at db/migrate

Comment: I have already realized my migration, I am only looking for a solution to add a line from the jquery or to do it during the hover

Comment: Use ajax to send a request(in client side you can't update databases and that is good for security reason): $.ajax({url: '/user_articles', method: 'POST', data: {id: myArticleId}}). Handle this request in the server by creating relevant action and route

Comment: I have make the following route:       post"/user_articles" => 'user_articles#create', :as => 'create' but i have somes erros(Bad Request) param is missing or the value is empty : user_activity

Comment: Look like userarticles_params have code as params.require(:user_activity).premit(...). If you want to use this construction you must change ajax data: $.ajax({url: '/user_articles', method: 'POST', data: {user_activity: {article_id: myArticleId}}}).


Also, you can write something like this without changing ajax request: UserArticle.create(user_id: current_user.id, article_id: params[:id])

Comment: I will test that thanks, 
is it possible to don't refresh the page, because it goes up every time

Answer (score 0):

You can create a form, but you can also create a dedicated action in your controller that is passed the article id, then you can change the `visibility` tracker to "seen" or to "1" if boolean

In your view, you should call this action on hover by following the section 2 of this thread : [Using :remote => true with hover event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381810/using-remote-true-with-hover-event)

You only have to mention the path to your dedicated action and also pass the article id. It avoid creating a form with hidden fields.

Finally, in order to remove the tab for the article, just put the javascript into a view file named like your action : `dedicated_action.erb.js` where you put some JS or Jquery code to make the div of the article disappear. The only thing you have to do in your original view with all articles is to assign an ID to the Div that is a container of the article, and use the same ID in the JS view in order to select the right DIV.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for not understanding everything but I am new on rails,
At the moment I have a form to add a User_activity:
Table that contains the id of the user and the article
and my functional hover
remains to put thats part together  to add in database when the mouse is hover the div

```
<script>
  $('.newness').hover(
    function() {
      $(this).addClass('hover);
      myArticleId = $(this).data('id');
      //I want there to put user_id & activity_id in my database
    }
  )
</script>
```

There is my model :

```
//appcontroller
def set_variables
@userarticle = UserArticle.new
end
//user_articles_controller
def create
@user = current_user
@userarticle = @user.user_articles.build(userarticles_params)
@userarticle.save
redirect_to root_path
end
```

Thanks